# Help Needed Plug and Play NAS (novice user)

Tags: hard-drive, nas

First of all, apologies if this question is too broad (I've searched the forum and not seen a similar question posted).

I am not that techie when it comes to command line scripts.

I want a NAS disk (2TB preferably) which I can just plug into my router and hope that Ubuntu recognises it and I don't need to faff about at command line level to get it working.

I search online stores for NAS storage / cloud storage and get lots of products displayed back, but none of them mention Linux compatibility (windows and mac yes), but no Linux / Ubuntu.

I can't afford to buy a NAS device, take it home and then find it doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Any tips or hints on (a) what to look for on my purchase or even (b) recommended a device would be helpful.

I know mods of the forum don't like questions that are generic or too broad, but I need a generic question answering as I find the whole area of NAS confusing.

Even external Hard Drives don't mention Linux when you look at the specs.

Any help much appreciated

Happy New Year

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu completely supports NAS in the same way that Mac + Windows do.

Most products do not mention having Linux support, but ultimately, they don't need to support Linux. Linux supports them. You will see plenty of this, but don't be discouraged! Where there is a will, there is a way, and 95% of the things you want to connect to your Linux box will, in fact, work.

Once you get it home, get it plugged in, Nautilus will automatically show it under "Network" - and if it doesn't, it is a pretty simple and straightforward thing to get it connected. All you have to do - in Nautilus' 'File' menu, select "Connect to Server" and enter the IP of the NAS - but you more than likely won't need to do that, but in case you do, this is what you would do:

1). Log in to your router's control panel (whichever one you connected the NAS to).

- In a browser, type the IP of your router, which is usually labelled on the router.
- The login name and password are also printed on the router.

2). Somewhere in there, there is a list of all devices connected. Find your NAS.
 - Note the IP of the NAS.

3). In Nautilus, go to File > Connect to Server
 - Input the IP you just got. If you got an error, append it with: 
   `smb://` --- i.e. `smb://192.168.1.18`

4). Voila! Nautilus will save the connection for subsequent uses.

There is basically no exception to this, and virtually any NAS storage drive you get that is Mac and Windows compatible will work just fine. (An Apple Time Capsule probably won't work)

The last time I dealt with an NAS, the thing actually had some version of Linux installed on it to drive the thing.

Comment: many thanks rm-vanda, that really helps, a little push in the right direction to help me feel confident :).

Comment: I would recommend a Western Digital NAS, btw.

Comment: And there are some additional instructions for you, in case the NAS you get DOES NOT automatically appear under "Network" in Nautilus (which is your default file explorer/manager, if you didn't know that already)

Comment: you have been most helpful @rm-vanda thank you very much for your assistance, I am sure I will be OK now :)

Comment: Anytime, and if you have any more troubles, you know where to go, there *is* a whole tag for that.

Comment: I bought a WD 4TB MyCloud NAS. I plugged it into my router , switched on and it it could be seen via Nautilus. Thanks again, everything worked as described. thanks @rm-vanda

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of help. Please don't forget to upvote, if you would.

Comment: cheers @rm-vanda rm-vanda , i am a newbie and my reputation isn't high enough to upvote yet !!! One thing I noticed about the WD NAS it that i have (on two occasions this week) had to reboot the NAS to make it viewable ! It has been OK for 48+ hours then needed a reboot just now !

Comment: You should be able to get the IP address of the NAS, one way or another, and follow the instructions above - In that case, It's File > Connect to Server, and after you do that successfully, it will at least always be in that menu as a recent server - I'm sure if you clicked around a bit, you could then find a way to pin it to your side bar...